# `bind` Equivalent to join (fmap f m)?

Tags: haskell, monads

This excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241990/409976) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234632/monads-with-join-instead-of-bind) demonstrates how `bind` can be written in terms of `join` and `fmap`:

`(>>=) :: m v -> (v -> m w) -> m w`

> says "if you have a strategy to produce a v, and for each v a
>   follow-on strategy to produce a w, then you have a strategy to produce
>   a w". How can we capture that in terms of join?

`mv >>= v2mw = join (fmap v2mw mv)`

But, I don't understand how `v2mw`, which has a type of `a -> m b` type checks to the first argument of `fmap`.

`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Comment: Let `b` be `m b` and `fmap v2mw :: f a -> f (m b)`. Then `join` forces `f` to equal `m` and collapses the layers.

Comment: Ah so `b` in `fmap` can be any type, including `m b`?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. The two `b`s arise in different contexts and are not required to be the same.

Comment: `The two bs arise in different contexts ` you're talking about the `b`'s in `fmap`'s signature: `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`? Surely the `b`'s must be the same type, no?

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant the `b` in `fmap`'s signature versus the `b` in the `m b` in `v2mw`'s/`(>>=)`'s signature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say `v2mw :: c -> m d`, just so things aren't ambiguous, and

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Then `fmap v2mw` works out so that `f ~ m`, `a ~ c` and `b ~ m d`, so

```
fmap v2mw :: m c -> m (m d)
```

and `join :: m (m e) -> m e`, so `join (fmap v2mw mv)` has type `m d` as expected.

Comment: "equals," or "is the same as."