# What is the intuitive meaning of "join"?

Tags: haskell, monads

What is the intuitive meaning of `join` for a Monad?

The *monads-as-containers* analogies make sense to me, and inside these analogies `join` makes sense. A value is double-wrapped and we unwrap one layer. But as we all know, a monad is not a container.

How might one write sensible, understandable code using `join` in normal circumstances, say when in `IO`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Monads with join instead of bind](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11234632/791604). Can you say whether this question's answers meet your needs, and if not, update your question with details about why so that we can target our answers to the parts you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the List monad, `join` is simply `concat`, and `concatMap` is `join . fmap`.
So `join` implicitly appears in any list expression which uses `concat`
or `concatMap`.

Suppose you were asked to find all of the numbers which are divisors of any
number in an input list. If you have a `divisors` function:

```
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors n = [ d | d <- [1..n], mod n d == 0 ]
```

you might solve the problem like this:

```
foo xs = concat $ (map divisors xs)
```

Here we are thinking of solving the problem by first mapping the
divisors function over all of the input elements and then concatenating
all of the resulting lists. You might even think that this is a very
"functional" way of solving the problem.

Another approch would be to write a list comprehension:

```
bar xs = [ d | x <- xs, d <- divisors x ]
```

or using do-notation:

```
bar xs = do x <- xs
            d <- divisors
            return d
```

Here it might be said we're thinking a little more
imperatively - first draw a number from the list `xs`;  then draw
 a divisors from the divisors of the number and yield it.

It turns out, though, that `foo` and `bar` are exactly the same function.

Morever, these two approaches are exactly the same in *any* monad.
That is, for any monad, and appropriate monadic functions f and g:

```
do x <- f      
   y <- g x           is the same as:    (join . fmap g) f
   return y
```

For instance, in the IO monad if we set `f = getLine` and `g = readFile`,
we have:

```
do x <- getLine
   y <- readFile x    is the same as:   (join . fmap readFile) getLine
   return y
```

The do-block is a more imperative way of expressing the action: first read a
line of input; then treat returned string as a file name, read the contents
of the file and finally return the result.

The equivalent join expression seems a little unnatural in the IO-monad.
However it shouldn't be as we are using it in exactly the same way as we
used `concatMap` in the first example.

Comment: To me, this was the most understandable explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An `action :: IO (IO a)` is a way of producing a way of producing an `a`. `join action`, then, is a way of producing an `a` by  running the outermost producer of `action`, taking the producer it produced and then running that as well, to finally get to that juicy `a`.

Answer (score 3):

`join` collapses consecutive layers of the type constructor.

A valid `join` must satisfy the property that, for any number of consecutive applications of the type constructor, it shouldn't matter the order in which we collapse the layers.

For example

```
ghci> let lolol = [[['a'],['b','c']],[['d'],['e']]]
ghci> lolol :: [[[Char]]]
ghci> lolol :: [] ([] ([] Char)) -- the type can also be expressed like this

ghci> join (fmap join lolol) -- collapse inner layers first
"abcde"
ghci> join (join lolol) -- collapse outer layers first
"abcde"
```

(We used `fmap` to "get inside" the outer monadic layer so that we could collapse the inner layers first.)

A small non container example where `join` is useful: for the function monad `(->) a`, `join` is equivalent to `\f x -> f x x`, a function of type `(a -> a -> b) -> a -> b` that applies two times the same argument to another function.

Answer (score 1):

Given an action that produces *another* action, run the action and then run the action that it produces.

If you imagine some kind of `Parser x` monad that parses an `x`, then `Parser (Parser x)` is a parser that does some parsing, and then returns another parser. So `join` would flatten this into a `Parser x` that just runs both actions and returns the final `x`.

Why would you even have a `Parser (Parser x)` in the first place? Basically, because `fmap`. If you have a parser, you can `fmap` a function that changes the result over it. But if you `fmap` a function that itself returns a parser, you end up with a `Parser (Parser x)`, where you probably want to just run both actions. `join` implements "just run both actions".

I like the parsing example because a parser typically has a `runParser` function. And it's clear that a `Parser Int` *is not* an integer. It's something that can *parse* an integer, *after* you give it some input to parse from. I think a lot of people end up thinking of an `IO Int` as being just a normal integer but with this annoying `IO` bit that you can't get rid of. *It isn't.* It's an unexecuted I/O operation. There's no integer "inside" it; the integer doesn't exist until you actually *perform* the I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I find these things easier to interpret by writing out the types and refactoring them a bit to reveal what the functions do.

### Reader monad

The `Reader` type is defined thus, and its `join` function has the type shown:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

join :: Reader r (Reader r a) -> Reader r a
```

Since this is a `newtype`, this means that the type `Reader r a` is **isomorphic** to `r -> a`.  So we can refactor the type definition to give us this type that, albeit it's not the same, it's really "the same" with scare quotes:

In the `(->) r` monad, which is isomorphic to `Reader r`, `join` is the function:

```
join :: (r -> r -> a) -> r -> a
```

So the `Reader` join is the function that takes a two-place function (`r -> r -> a`) and applies to the same value at both its argument positions.

### Writer monad

Since the `Writer` type has this definition:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }
```

...then when we remove the `newtype`, its `join` function has a type isomorphic to:

```
join :: Monoid w => ((a, w), w) -> (a, w)
```

The `Monoid` constraint needs to be there because the `Monad` instance for `Writer` requires it, and it lets us guess right away what the function does:

```
join ((a, w0), w1) = (a, w0 <> w1)
```

### State monad

Similarly, since `State` has this definition:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

...then its `join` is like this:

```
join :: (s -> (s -> (a, s), s)) -> s -> (a, s)
```

...and you can also venture just writing it directly:

```
join f s0 = (a, s2)
  where 
    (g, s1) = f s0
    (a, s2) = g s1


{- Here's the "map" to the variable names in the function:

               f     g      s2   s1      s0        s2
    join :: (s -> (s -> (a, s ), s )) -> s  -> (a, s )
-}
```

If you stare at this type a bit, you might think that it bears some resemblance to *both* the `Reader` and `Writer`'s types for their `join` operations.  And you'd be right!  The `Reader`, `Writer` and `State` monads are all instances of a more general pattern called [update monads](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/heap-of-successes).

### List monad

```
join :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

As other people have pointed out, this is the type of the `concat` function.

### Parsing monads

Here comes a really neat thing to realize.  Very often, "fancy" monads turn out to be combinations or variants of "basic" ones like `Reader`, `Writer`, `State` or lists.  So often what I do when confronted with a novel monad is ask: which of the basic monads does it resemble, and how?

Take for example parsing monads, which have been brought up in other answers here.  A simplistic parser monad (with no support for important things like error reporting) looks like this:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

A `Parser` is a function that takes a string as input, and returns a list of *candidate parses*, where each candidate parse is a pair of:

1. A parse result of type `a`;
2. The *leftovers* (the suffix of the input string that was not consumed in that parse).

But notice that this type looks very much like the state monad:

```
newtype Parser  a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }
newtype State s a = State  { runState  :: s      ->  (a, s)       }
```

And this is no accident!  Parser monads are *nondeterministic state monads*, where the state is the unconsumed portion of the input string, and parse steps generate *alternatives* that may be later rejected in light of further input.  List monads are often called "nondeterminism" monads, so it's no surprise that a parser resembles a mix of the state and list monads.

And this intuition can be systematized by using **monad transfomers**.  The state monad transformer is defined like this:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

Which means that the `Parser` type from above can be written like this as well:

```
type Parser a = StateT String [] a
```

...and its `Monad` instance follows *mechanically* from those of `StateT` and `[]`.

### The `IO` monad

Imagine we could enumerate all of the possible *primitive* `IO` actions, somewhat like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Command a where
  -- An action that writes a char to stdout
  putChar :: Char -> Command ()

  -- An action that reads a char from stdin
  getChar :: Command Char

  -- ...
```

Then we could think of the `IO` type as this (which I've adapted from the highly-recommended [Operational monad tutorial](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html)):

```
data IO a where
  -- An `IO` action that just returns a constant value.
  Return :: a -> IO a

  -- An action that binds the result of a `Command` to 
  -- a function that computes the next step after it.
  Bind :: Command x -> (x -> IO a) -> IO a

instance Monad IO where ...
```

Then `join` action would then look like this:

```
join :: IO (IO a) -> IO a

-- If the action is just `Return`, then its payload already
-- is what we need to return.
join (Return ioa) = ioa

-- If the action is a `Bind`, then its "next step" function
-- `f` produces `IO (IO a)`, so we can just recursively stick 
-- a `join` to its result end.
join (Bind cmd f) = Bind cmd (join . f)
```

So all that the `join` does here is "chase down" the `IO` action until it sees a result that fits the pattern `Return (ma :: IO a)`, and strip out the outer `Return`.

So what did I do here?  Just like for parser monads, I just defined (or rather copied) a  toy model of the `IO` type that has the virtue of being *transparent*.  Then I work out the behavior of `join` from the toy model.