# Haskell concatMap point free explanation

Tags: haskell

I am struggling to figure out how `concatMap` relates to the `=<<` operator. Could someone please explain why:

`f x = concatMap g $ take 5 $ x`

becomes

`f = (g =<<) . take 5`

<del>in point free.</del>  I can see that the types of `concatMap` and `=<<` match but I don't understand why.

Comment: `f = concatMap g . take 5` would also be point-free. `a >>= f` is `concatMap f a` because that’s the definition of the list monad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution of `=<<` for `concatMap` has nothing to do with point-free'ness.

`>>=` for lists is defined to be a combination of `concat` and `map` (which is in turn equivalent to `concatMap`):

```
xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

and of course `=<<` is just `>>=` flipped.

An explanation of the monad instance for lists can be found at: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List

Comment: yes, my question was asked poorly. Just reading up on what you wrote..  thanks. Reading up on what you wrote, Is it also a good way of thinking  about it along the lines that  `concatMap` is `join fmap` for lists (and indeed all monads)

Comment: @matthias `concatMap = concat .: map = (concat .) . map` by definition, and for lists `map = fmap` and `concat = join`, so. And, in general, [`((g<=<f)=<<) = (g=<<).(f=<<) = join.(g<$>).join.(f<$>)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234632/monads-with-join-instead-of-bind/11249714#11249714).