# Which Algebraic Pattern fits this type of tree?

Tags: haskell, monads, comonad

I've got a puzzle for you,

I managed to write some code that would do these things using recursion-schemes, but it's incredibly messy
and that usually means that I missed a useful abstraction somewhere.

I'm designing a layout system for my text editor
[`Rasa`](https://github.com/chrispenner/rasa); It uses splits in a very similar
manner as Vim. I decided to describe the splits using a Tree; you can imagine
it as a binary tree of either vertical or horizontal splits with 'Views' at the
leaf nodes. [This
picture](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c3d68b5b37318799846cb3c668ffac851a7fe463/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f334f3042305532493034316334323075313633772f746d757825323076696d25323070616e65732532306861636b2e706e67)
might help.

Here's my initial data structure:

```
data Direction = Hor | Vert
data Tree a = 
  Branch Direction (Tree a) (Tree a)
  | Leaf a
  deriving (Functor)
```

Some of the operations I need are:

- `split :: (View -> Tree View) -> Tree View -> Tree View` 
  Which splits nodes (or not) into two nodes horizontally or vertically (while maintaining their position in 
  the tree)
- `close :: (View -> Bool) -> Tree View -> Tree View` which 'closes' any views which match the predicate by removing
  them from the tree and re-organizing adjacent views properly.
- `fmap`; I'd like the tree to be a functor so I can alter the views.

Some nice to have features:
- `focusRight :: Tree View -> Tree View`, Sets a View to be active if and only if the nearest horizontally joined
    view to the left WAS active

I'm looking for an abstraction or set of abstractions which would provide this
functionality in a clean way. Here's my thought process so far:

At first I thought I had a Monoid, The identity was the empty tree, and
`mappend` would just attach another branch to the tree, but this doesn't work
since I have two operations: vertical append and horizontal append and the operations
aren't associative when they're mixed together.

Next I thought 'Some of my operations depend on their context' so I probably have a Comonad. The version of the tree
I have doesn't work as a co-monad because I don't have a value to `extract` on a Branch, so I restructured my tree
like this:

```
data Tree a = Node Direction [Tree a] a [Tree a]
    deriving (Functor)
```

but this still
didn't handle the case of 'splitting' a node based on what was inside it, this matched the signature `(View -> Tree View) ->
Tree View -> Tree View`, which unifies with `bind` from  Monad, so maybe I had a monad? I can implement monad for the
original Tree definition, but can't figure it out for my Comonad tree version.

Is there a way I can get the best of both worlds here? Am I digging up the wrong tree with Comonad/Monad?
Basically I'm looking for an elegant way to model these functions over my data-structure. Thanks!

If you want to see the full code, the functions are [here](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/rasa/blob/master/rasa-ext-views/src/Rasa/Ext/Views/Internal/Views.hs) and the current tree is [here](https://github.com/ChrisPenner/rasa/blob/master/rasa-ext-views/src/Rasa/Ext/Views/Internal/BiTree.hs).

Comment: @pigworker has a whole [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QojLQY5H0RI) and a good chunk of a [paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf) all about using monads (over indexed sets) to carve up 2D space

Comment: @benjamin-hodgson Oh awesome thanks! TBH at a first glance the paper seems a bit out of my league; I've only just scratched the surface of Type Families; so the type-level programming in that paper is going to be a bit of a reach for me. That said, I'll definitely watch the video and give reading through the paper a try! Simpler solutions are also appreciated :)

Comment: Tangential suggestion: consider using [`LambdaCase`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XLambdaCase) in your *recursion-schemes* code. YMMV, but I find it makes the definitions of the (co)algebras a lot easier on the eyes.

Comment: @ChrisPenner Understood! A potted summary: your first `Tree` (whose `Monad` grafts trees together) is along the right lines, but it doesn't work because keeping the sizes of the constituent boxes lined up is tricky. (If you replace `a`s with `b`s using `fmap` you'd better make sure the `b`s don't occupy more 2D space than the `a`s did!) Lindley and McBride's idea is to snap boxes together at the type level and expose an indexed monad interface, which forbids users from bending spacetime. FWIW I think the Hasochism paper is an excellent intro to fancy types in general, not just this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave up trying to cram this into a comment. [Conor McBride](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker) has a whole [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QojLQY5H0RI) and, with Sam Lindley, a big chunk of a [paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf), all about using monads to carve up 2D space. Since you asked for an elegant solution I feel compelled to give you a potted summary of their work, although I wouldn't necessarily advise building this into your codebase - I suspect it's probably simpler just to work with a library like [`boxes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boxes) and hand-crank the cutting and resizing logic with manual error handling.

---

Your first `Tree` is a step in the right direction. We can write a `Monad` instance to graft trees together:

```
instance Monad Tree where
    return = Leaf
    Leaf x >>= f = f x
    Branch d l r >>= f = Branch d (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

[`Tree`'s `join`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241990/1523776) takes a tree with trees at its leaves and lets you walk all the way to the bottom without stopping for breath half way down. It may be helpful to think of `Tree` as a [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#t:Free), as @danidiaz has shown in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892697/1523776). Or [Kmett might say](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/bound) that you have a very simple syntax permitting term substitution whose `Var` is called `Leaf`.

Anyway, the point is you can use `>>=` to grow trees by progressively chopping up their leaves. Here I have a one-dimensional UI (let's forget about `Direction` for the moment) with a single window containing a `String`, and by repeatedly cutting it in half I end up with eight smaller windows.

```
halve :: [a] -> Tree [a]
halve xs = let (l, r) = splitAt (length xs `div` 2) xs
         in Node (Leaf l) (Leaf r)

ghci> let myT = Leaf "completeshambles"
-- |completeshambles|
ghci> myT >>= halve
Node (Leaf "complete") (Leaf "shambles")
-- |complete|shambles|
ghci> myT >>= halve >>= halve
Node (Node (Leaf "comp") (Leaf "lete")) (Node (Leaf "sham") (Leaf "bles"))
-- |comp|lete|sham|bles|
ghci> myT >>= halve >>= halve >>= halve
Node (Node (Node (Leaf "co") (Leaf "mp")) (Node (Leaf "le") (Leaf "te"))) (Node (Node (Leaf "sh") (Leaf "am")) (Node (Leaf "bl") (Leaf "es")))
-- |co|mp|le|te|sh|am|bl|es|
```

(In real life you'd probably only be cutting up one window at a time, by checking its ID inside your binding function and returning it unchanged if it's not the one you're looking for.)

The problem is, `Tree` has no understanding of the fact that physical space is a limited and precious resource. `fmap` lets you replace `a`s with `b`s, but the resulting structure won't fit on the screen if the `b`s take up more space than the `a`s did!

```
ghci> fmap ("in" ++) myT
Leaf "incompleteshambles"
```

This gets more serious in two dimensions, because boxes can push each other around and tear. If the middle window gets accidentally resized, I either get a misshapen box or a hole in the middle (depending on whereabouts in the tree it was).

```
+-+-+-+         +-+-+-+            +-+-+  +-+
| | | |         | | | |            | | |  | |
+-+-+-+         +-+-+-++-+   or,   +-+-+--+-+
| | | |  ---->  | |    | | perhaps | |    | |
+-+-+-+         +-+-+-++-+         +-+-+--+-+
| | | |         | | | |            | | |  | |
+-+-+-+         +-+-+-+            +-+-+  +-+
```

Expanding a window is a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do, but in the real world the space it expands into has to come from somewhere. You can't grow one window without shrinking another, and vice versa. This is not the sort of operation which can be done with `>>=`, which performs local substitutions at individual leaf nodes; you need to look at a window's siblings to know who's taking up the space adjacent to it.

---

So you shouldn't be allowed to use `>>=` to resize content like that. Lindley and McBride's idea is to teach the type checker how to snap boxes together. Using type-level natural numbers and addition,

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
type family n :+ m where
    Z :+ m = m
    S n :+ m = S (n :+ m)
```

they work with content indexed by its width and height. (In the paper they use 2D matrices represented as vectors of vectors, but for efficiency you may want to use an array with a phantom type measuring its size.)

```
a, Box a :: (Nat, Nat) -> *
-- so Box :: ((Nat, Nat) -> *) -> (Nat, Nat) -> *
```

Placing two boxes side by side using `Hor` requires that they have the same height, and placing them above each other with `Ver` requires that they have the same width.

```
data Box a wh where
    Content :: a '(w, h) -> Box a '(w, h)
    Hor :: Box a '(w1, h) -> Box a '(w2, h) -> Box a '(w1 :+ w2, h)
    Ver :: Box a '(w, h1) -> Box a '(w, h2) -> Box a '(w, h1 :+ h2)
```

Now we're ready to build a monad to graft together these trees. The semantics of `return` haven't changed - it puts a 2D object in a `Box` on its own.

```
return :: a wh -> Box a wh
return = Content
```

Now let's think about `>>=`. In general a box is made up of a number of pieces of `Content` of varying size, composed somehow to produce a larger box. Below I have three pieces of content sized 2x1, 2x2 and 1x3 making up a 3x3 box. This box will look something like `Hor (Ver (Content 2x1) (Content 2x2)) Content 1x3`.

```
 2x1
+--+-+
|  | |
+--+ |1x3
|  | |
|  | |
+--+-+
 2x2
```

While you, the caller of `>>=`, know the outer measurements of your box, you don't know the dimensions of the individual pieces of content that make it up. How can you be expected to preserve the size of the content when you cut it up with `>>=`? You'll have to write a function which preserves the size without *a priori* knowledge of what the size was.

So `>>=` takes a `Box` of a known size `wh`, takes it apart to find the content, processes it with a function which preserves the (unknown) size of the content you give it*, and puts it back together to produce a new box with the same size `wh`. Note the rank-2 type, reflecting the fact that the caller of `>>=` has no control over the dimensions of content the continuation will be called with.

```
(>>=) :: Box a wh -> (forall wh2. a wh2 -> Box b wh2) -> Box b wh
Content x >>= f = f x
Hor l r >>= f = Hor (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
Ver t b >>= f = Ver (t >>= f) (b >>= f)
```

If you use a type synonym `~>` for index-preserving functions and flip the arguments, you get something which looks just like `=<<` for regular `Monad`s, but with a different kind of arrow. Kleisli composition also comes out looking quite pretty.

```
type a ~> b = forall x. a x -> b x

return :: a ~> Box a
(=<<) :: (a ~> Box b) -> (Box a ~> Box b)
(>=>) :: (a ~> Box b) -> (b ~> Box c) -> (a ~> Box c)
```

So that's monads over indexed sets. (More in [*Kleisli Arrows of Outrageous Fortune*](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf).) In [the paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf) they build a bunch more infrastructure to support cropping and rearranging boxes, which would probably be useful to you building a UI. For efficiency you might also decide to track the currently focused window using a [zipper](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/seminare/2005/advanced-fp/docs/huet-zipper.pdf), which is a fun exercise. Incidentally I think *Hasochism* is a great introduction to fancy types in general, not just as a solution to this particular problem.

<sup>*Assuming that `a`'s index is indeed an accurate measure of its physical size</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'll read this over ASAP, just wanted to let you know that tracking space allocated to each box actually isn't super important in my case; the structure of which boxes are appended to which in which direction is the most important part :)

Comment: @ChrisPenner Well, in that case the original `Tree` and its `Monad` instance should be enough (and hopefully the first half of my answer is a good enough explanation of how that works) - but how do you propose to avoid accidentally resizing content?

Comment: It's for a text editor, the "boxes" are viewports into buffers, I think it's reasonable for the viewports to resize themselves any time one of them is split or closed. In any case we can guarantee we resize at most 1 window. How can we use monad to implement close?

Comment: I really appreciate you going through the trouble to explain this in depth! I'm excited to dive into it tomorrow :) I've been hoping to get further into type programming, this should help get me started!

Comment: @ChrisPenner IDK your exact use case but I'm thinking about the case where an `fmap` accidentally resizes the `a` in one of your leaf nodes and pushes the other windows around - see the diagram about half way through the post. `close` should be easy - if you close the 1x3 box in my example above the two other boxes should expand to take its place. I expect there's only one way to make it type check: replace the closed window's parent with its sibling, after widening the sibling's nearest child(ren) by the same amount. It's 3AM here so I'm happy to answer any further questions tomorrow :)

Comment: I'll use the intuitive Monad instance for split, but will probably stick with my recursion-schemes implementation for the other operations since it seems as though there's not a clear abstraction for that form of operation. This type theory stuff is really cool (and I'll definitely be referencing back to it) but is a little heavy-handed for my use-case. Thanks for your help :) I'm going to leave it open for another few days in case others have comments, but I'll come back and accept then!

Answer (score 1):

I would represent your type as a monad and use `>>=` to handle `split`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import Control.Monad.Free

data Direction = Hor | Vert

data TreeF a = TreeF Direction a a deriving Functor

type Tree a = Free TreeF a
```

As for `close`, I would probably use [`cata`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:project) or `para` from **recursion-schemes**, since `close` seems to work bottom-up and require at most knowledge of node parents and siblings. You could also turn to [`Control.Lens.Plated`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#t:Plated).

Incidentally, `Free` already has a [`Recursive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#t:Recursive) instance. `FreeF TreeF a` would be the corresponding algebra. But you mentioned that it didn't work out very well.

Working directly with the `Free` and `FreeT` constuctors might prove cumbersome. Perhaps some pattern synonyms could help there.