# Understanding monadic function composition

Tags: list, haskell, monads, function-composition, kleisli

I am learning about monads from the book 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca. I am trying to understand the associativity law for monads. Essentially, the law states that when you have a chain of monadic function applications with `>>=`, it shouldn't matter how they're nested.

The following code enables one to pass the result of a function of type `a -> m b` to a function of type `b -> m c`:

```
(<=<) :: (Monad m) => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)
f <=< g = (\x -> g x >>= f)
```

However, for the example below:

```
ghci> let f x = [x, -x]
ghci> let g x = [x*3, x*2]
ghci> let h = f <=< g
ghci> h 3
[9, -9, 6, -6]
```

Are `f x` and `g x` both functions? It seems to be that they are lists with different values of x and not functions. How does the line `let h = f <=< g` work in the above code? `f` and `g` have to be functions since they are used with `<=<` but I am not sure what they are.

Comment: `f` and `g` are functions. `f x` and `g x` are lists (assuming there is a variable `x` in scope; otherwise they are errors).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f x = [x, -x]
```

This is ordinary function definition syntax. We are *defining* a new function `f`, by writing down what it would produce when applied to a hypothetical value `x`.

`let` (whether as a statement or a `let ... in ...` expression) just introduces a block where you can make definitions, much like `where`. The definitions themselves use the same syntax as global ones do.

If you know how to define functions by writing e.g. `plusOne n = n + 1` in a file, then this syntax is exactly the same (if you don't know how to do that, then I'd suggest reading through some introductory tutorials on fundamental Haskell syntax before you try to understand monadic function composition).

So after those definitions `f` and `g` are functions. `f x` and `g x` don't really make sense, since you don't have an `x` in scope to apply them to.

If you did have such a value in scope, then `f x` would be an expression that evaluates to a list, which involves *calling* the function `f`. It still wouldn't be true to say that `f x` or `g x` are functions.

So now it should be clear that `let h = f <=< g` is defining a new value `h` by applying the `<=<` operator to `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing's better for gaining a feeling of understanding, like working through the definitions by hand on a sheet of paper.

`f x = [x, -x]` can also be written `f = (\ x -> [x, -x])`. Thus

```
  h 3 
= {- by def of h -}
  (f <=< g) 3 
= {- by def of (<=<) -}
  (\x -> g                   x >>= f               ) 3
= {- by defs of f and g -}
  (\x -> (\ x -> [x*3, x*2]) x >>= (\ x -> [x, -x])) 3
= {- by substitution -}
         (\ x -> [x*3, x*2]) 3 >>= (\ x -> [x, -x])
= {- by substitution -}
                 [3*3, 
                  3*2]         >>= (\ x -> [x, -x])
= {- by definition of (>>=) for [] -}
  concat [       (3*3)         &   (\ x -> [x, -x])  -- x & f == f x
         ,       (3*2)         &   (\ x -> [x, -x]) 
         ]
= {- by definition of concat -}
                 (3*3)         &   (\ x -> [x, -x])
         ++      (3*2)         &   (\ x -> [x, -x]) 
= 
  [9, -9, 6, -6]
```

(*edit*) For a picture, and some more discussion of these *Kleisli arrows* and their composability, see [this older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249714/849891).