# Map/reduce equivalent for a list comprehension with multiple for clauses

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, list-comprehension, fold

I want to write a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) equivalent of the list comprehensions using higher-order functions only and without side effects. I do this for strictly learning purposes. *I know that list comprehensions are Pythonic.* In Python `map(f, xs)` is equivalent to `[f(x) for x in xs]`. But what are the equivalents of these below?

- A: `[f(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]`
- B: `[f(x, y) for x in range(1, 5) for y in range(x, 5)]`

`map` only returns lists of the same length. `reduce` is more general, you can implement `map` and `filter` upon it.

```
map(f, xs) == reduce(lambda a, e: a + [f(e)], xs, [])
filter(p, xs) == reduce(lambda a, e: a + [e] if p(e) else a, xs, [])
```

Therefore A can be implemented as:

```
def map2(f, xs, ys):
    reduce(lambda a, x: a + map(lambda y: f(x, y), ys), xs, [])
```

But this doesn't generalize to >2 for clauses. And B is even more tricky, as the iteration variable from 1st for clause is used in the 2nd clause. How do i write a function (or set of functions) that implement list comprehension functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the pattern of a [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29), specifically the list monad. In many languages, monads are hidden behind some kind of syntactic sugar, such as C#'s [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), Scala's [sequence comprehensions](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/111), Haskell's [do-notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation) or, in even more languages, (multi-)list comprehensions (like here in Python).

The key term in translating from any of these sugary syntaxes to ordinary functions is (in the special case of lists) a function of type `([a], a -> [b]) -> [b]`, which is the essential part of the definition of a monad. This function is known under different names, e.g. [`(>>=)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) or "bind", [`flatMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) or `concatMap`, or [`selectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For the case of lists, `concatMap` or `flatMap` is probably the best name, because that's what it does: map a function, which returns lists, over a list, giving a list of lists; then, flatten that list.

---

Now for something more concrete<sup>1</sup>:

```
> from functools import reduce
> from operator import add
> def concatMap(xs, f):
      return reduce(add, map(f, xs), []) # only map and reduce!
```

Testing:

```
> [x*y for x in range(1 ,5) for y in range(x, 5)]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
> concatMap(range(1, 5), lambda x: concatMap(range(x, 5), lambda y:[x*y]))
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16]
```

And more fun:

```
> [x*y+z for x in range(1, 5) for y in range(x, 5) for z in range(x, y)]
> [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15]
> concatMap(range(1, 5),lambda x: concatMap(range(x, 5), lambda y: concatMap(range(x, y),lambda z: [x*y+z])))
> [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15]
```

---

Finally, it should be noted that though a `map`-like function is always required for a monad, in general `reduce` is not enough -- what's actually needed is a generalized "flattening" operation [`join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382210/monad-join-function), with a type like `m<m<a>>`, (using template/generics syntax), where `m` is the type of the monad in question.

<sup>1</sup>As noted in the comments, this can also be defined as `concatMap = lambda xs, f: chain.from_iterable(map(f, xs))`, using `itertools` and the identity `(>>=) ≡ join . fmap`.

Comment: Instead of the proposed concatMap, I'd use itertools.chain.from_iterable. The equivalent of bind is lambda f, it: itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.starmap(f, it))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.starmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for case **A**:

```
from itertools import product, starmap
list(starmap(f, product(xs, ys)))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> [mul(x, y) for x in range(1, 4) for y in 'abc']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> list(starmap(mul, product(range(1, 4), 'abc')))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```