# Instance of Monad for Multiple Data Constructors

Tags: haskell, monads

I've started Haskell not too long ago, and am now teaching myself about monads, so I've come up with a dumb example for myself here to assist me in understanding an aspect of monads.

Given a type `Certainty` defined as

```
data Certainty a = Definitely a | Perhaps a | Nope
```

and an instance of `Monad` for said type

```
instance Monad Certainty where
  return = ...
```

how would the method `return` be defined for Certainty and each of its data constructors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to pick one - based on the naming I would suggest

```
return value = Definitely value
```

remember that `return a >>= f` must be `f a`

**bind** should probably be

```
(Definitely a) >>= f = f a
(Perhaps a)    >>= f = case f a of
                          Definitely b -> Perhaps b
                          Perhaps b    -> Perhaps b
                          Nope         -> Nope
Nope           >>= _ = Nope
```

Comment: This is the `WriterT Any Maybe` monad, where we interpret `Definitely a` as `Just (False, a)`, `Perhaps a` as `Just (True, a)`, and `Nope` as `Nothing` (with appropriate newtype wrapping all around).

Comment: or just my take on *probably* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Carsten's answer is quite correct, of course, but it is, in my experience, often [more intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382210/monad-join-function)  to specify a monad by defining the `join` function (especially in this case, where any child will understand that if Mum says that we will *perhaps definitely* have ice cream tomorrow that means that we will *perhaps* have ice cream..)

```
join :: Certainty (Certainty a) -> Certainty a

join Nope                        = Nope
join (Perhaps Nope)              = Nope
join (Perhaps (Perhaps x))       = Perhaps x 
join (Perhaps (Definitely x))    = Perhaps x
join (Definitely Nope)           = Nope
join (Definitely (Perhaps x))    = Perhaps x
join (Definitely (Definitely x)) = Definitely x
```

Of course, `>>=` can be defined in terms of `join` and `fmap` (which is trivial for `Certainty`, and can be automatically found by `ghc` with `-XDeriveFunctor`) by

```
x >>= f = join (fmap f x)
```

which makes my definition equivalent to Carsten's

Moreover, by looking at the last three lines of the definition of `join` we see that for all `x :: Certainty a` we have `join (Definitely x) = x` which suggests that

```
 return x = Definitely x
```